# How to run multiple commands with command module in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to run couple of commands in ansible playbook I am trying below:

```
 - name: Running multiple cmds
   command:
    - |
      cmd2
      cmd2
      cmd3
      cmd4
```

But i am getting an error on this task while running above code.

**Update**: I am trying to use below commands using command module but getting an error:

```
- name: install pexpect using pip
  shell: /bin/bash -c "pip install pexpect"

- name: Join system to AD 
  expect:
    command: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
      - source /etc/os-release
      - realm join --membership-software=adcli --user=username@EXAMPLE.COM --computer-ou="OU={{ env }},OU={{ account }},OU=XXXX,OU=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXX" --os-name="$PRETTY_NAME" --os-version="$VERSION" <DCNAME>
    responses:
        Password for *: "{{ username | b64decode }}"
```

Error:

```
TASK [adjoin : Join system to AD] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/ansiblepull/playbooks/roles/adjoin/tasks/main.yml': line 58, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Join system to AD\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Can anyone help me in solving this.

I am getting an error while syntax-check as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed updated error with the below module:

```
- name: Join system to AD 
  expect:
    command: /bin/bash -c "realm join --membership-software=adcli --user=username@EXAMPLE.COM --computer-ou="OU={{ xxx }},OU={{ xxxx }},OU=xxxx,OU=xxxxx,DC=xxxxxxxx,DC=xxxx" --os-name={{ ansible_distribution }} --os-version={{ ansible_distribution_version }} DCNAME"
    responses:
        Password for *: "{{ join_user_pass | b64decode }}"
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-module) states that the command module doesn't get a shell

> The command(s) will not be processed through the shell

The `command` module takes the command as an argument, so you can't have  list as you've written there. You could do the same thing in a `loop:` with `command: {{ item }}` :

```
- name: "Run {{ item }}"
  command: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - cmd2
    - cmd2 
    - cmd3
```

You could also have several `command:` tasks instead.

However, this is generally considered bad practice (E.g. E303 from [Ansible Lint rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/rules/default_rules.html)) because it tends to break idempotency. It would be better to decompose those commands into something that uses Ansible modules.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked Anyways the commands which i would like to run those do not have ansible modules to replace it with.

Comment: Can you please help me with an updated error.

Comment: I use the shell module but I am facing a similar problem. Shouldn't the shell module take care of multiple commands separated by a newline? My snippet is mentioned here: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/17382/38593