# Multiple shell commands not executing with shell module

Tags: ansible

For some reason this fails:

```yaml
- name: "Get GPG key from the Jenkins portal"
  get_url:
    url: https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key
    dest: /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key
- name: "Delete existing keys and de-arm"
  become: true
  shell: |
     "rm -rf /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg"
     "gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key"
```

This is a part of a tasks file that gets called from another file. I do not see why the first should fail. The failure reason is:

```json
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "\"rm -rf /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg\"\n\"gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key\"\n",
    "delta": "0:00:00.021351",
    "end": "2023-02-07 12:00:17.975367",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "\"rm -rf /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg\"\n\"gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key\"\n",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 127,
    "start": "2023-02-07 12:00:17.954016",
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: rm -rf /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg: not found\n/bin/sh: 2: gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key: not found",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: 1: rm -rf /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg: not found",
        "/bin/sh: 2: gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key: not found"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

I don't know what `not found` means in this context. I can run these very commands in sequence on a real shell and they work.

```yaml
- name: "Get GPG key from the Jenkins portal"
  get_url:
    url: https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key
    dest: /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key
- name: "Delete existing key"
  become: true
  shell: "rm -rf /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg"
- name: "De-arm the keys"
  become: true
  shell: "gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key"
  register: jenkinskey
```

Since these get processed via the shell, they should be fine I believe.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I do not see why the first should fail.*

It looks like the task has a syntax error

```yaml
- name: "Delete existing keys and de-arm"
  become: true
  shell: |
     "rm -rf /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg"
     "gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key"
```

According the error message

```yaml
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: rm -rf /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg: not found\n/bin/sh: 2: gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key: not found",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: 1: rm -rf /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg: not found",
        "/bin/sh: 2: gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key: not found"
```

The lines are processed as one single command and if I interpret it correctly. Furthermore, no quotes are necessary.

> *I don't know what `not found` means in this context.*

It means that the command as a whole or parts of it wasn't found, a syntax error and is the expected behavior.

**Possible Solution**

You could try with

```yaml
  - name: Exec sh script on Remote Node
    shell:
      cmd: |
        rm -f /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg
        gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.io.key
    register: result
```

or even with

```yaml
    shell: "rm -f /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg && gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins.gpg"
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to execute a shell script on a Remote Node using Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73594837/6771046)

**Further Recommendation**

Instead of using the `shell` module implement the commands with Ansible modules

- [`file` module – Manage files and file properties](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html)
- [How can I manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d within an Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585303/)